# What was the Lockheed design solution for the shuttle SRB field joint and how was it superior to the failure prone Morton Thiokol field joint?

Tags: failure, srb, shuttle-challenger

In an effort to quickly post this question I've elected to (for the moment) not provide links to my searches.

I've found tons of references, studies, reports, images etc to the failed Thiokol field joint and its redesign but find nothing regarding the reportedly superior design solution that Lockheed proposed.

[image: comparison of Thiokol original v redesign]

Does anyone have information on any of the other 3 SRB proposals? SRBs can have 3 joints... 'factory' case to case joint, 'field' case to case joint and case to nozzle joint. Does anyone have information on the 'other' joints?

**QUESTION:**  can someone provide details and images of the Lockheed proposed space shuttle SRB field joint?

Comment: Your title and question don't match, you are also making the assumption that Lockheed joint was better without evidence.

Comment: I assume that your question is a follow-up [to this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/60791/why-were-they-using-segmented-boosters-on-space-shuttle/60792#60792) on why the Shuttle used segmented SRBs (despite introducing the risk of burning fuel leaking through a field joint).

Comment: @dan04 yes... absolutely. I've spent a career in product design and have been involved in countless 'down-selects' where choices are made in which certain solutions are advanced and others cut off. Sometimes the deciding factor is schedule, other times it is cost, sometimes TRL. I'd love to see the Lockheed field joint!

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer: Image of the joint, no attempt to describe if or why it was better.

[image]

From [TECHNICAL REPORT
ANALYSIS AND DESIGN
STUDY OF SOLID ROCKET MOTORS
FOR A SPACE SHUTTLE BOOSTER Volume 2 Book 1](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19720015125/downloads/19720015125.pdf)

Search for the title of this document on NASA NTRS and you will get a fun weekend of reading.

https://ntrs.nasa.gov/search?q=study%20of%20solid%20rocket%20motors%20for%20a%20space%20shuttle%20booster